# Example from MSDN does not work - try/finally

Tags: c#, exception

I have been reading about try/finally on MSDN and found out following code. They say it WILL run the Finally clause but when I run it, it just does not continue and does not run it. What is the problem?

```
 public class TestTryFinally
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int i = 123;
            string s = "Some string";
            object o = s;

            try
            {
                // Invalid conversion; o contains a string not an int
                i = (int)o;
            }

            finally
            {
                Console.Write("i = {0}", i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me. It will indeed run the finally block. My guess is that the debugger is popping up a dialog box for you, and you're not managing to force execution to continue.

Run it not under the debugger - that will avoid the debugger getting in the way as it tries to "help" you.

Comment: Can you explain what "popping up" is, please?

Comment: @Simon: He means the exception popup.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the window is not closing so fast that you do not notice?

Put in a readline to make it wait:

```
public class TestTryFinally
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int i = 123;
            string s = "Some string";
            object o = s;

            try
            {
                // Invalid conversion; o contains a string not an int
                i = (int)o;
            }

            finally
            {
                Console.Write("i = {0}", i);
                Console.Write("Press Enter to continue.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Jon Skeet's answer, the debugger will not pop up if you catch the exception.

```
try {
    i = (int)o;
}
catch(InvalidCastException e) {}
finally {
    Console.Write("i = {o}",i);
}
```